# execute a procedure one server A that pulls from server B

Tags: sql, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

In SSIS (SQL Server 2008 R2), I'm using an `OLE DB Command` to repeatedly execute a procedure. The procedure is located on server A and calls server B. How do I let the `OLE DB Command` know how to access server B? (I can't move the procedure to server B.)

Step-by-step:

- In the "Advanced Editor for OLE DB Command"->"Connection Managers" tab, I select server A.
- In the "Advanced Editor for OLE DB Command"->"Component Properties" tab, I type "Exec myProc ?"
- The "Column Mappings" gives an error: "Syntax error, permission violation, or other nonspecific error".

Thank you for the responses!

Comment: A stored procedure exists in a database on Server A. It does not exist in a different database on Server B. Your desire is to make the stored procedure run against Server B (assuming they have the all the same tables involved on B)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for a "Linked Server".  It took me awhile to find it because in SQL Server Management Studio it's not under the database, but under the server itself in the "Server Objects" folder.

Once I made this in Management Studio the SSIS package could call the procedure without an issue.